# Pass arguments to Cygwin through a python program

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, python-2.7, bpython

I came across `bpython` and tried to installed it on my windows system with the help of `cygwin`. Now, whenever I have to access `bpython` program I have to open cygwin and than write bpython inside the cygwin shell.

Now I am trying to automate the above process using a python script.So, that as soon as I write `bpython.py` in my windows `command prompt` it should directly open `bpython shell` for me.

My code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('F:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat')
```

Using above code I am able to create `cygwin` process but than again I have to write `bpython` in cygwin terminal to get it working.

[image]

So, I was wondering can I directly pass `bpython` as an `argument` to the `F:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat`  something like

```
F:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat bpython
```

which can directly open the bpython shell.

OR is it possible that

1) First I create `cygwin` process with the help of `subprocess` module.

2) Than I pass `bpython` as an argument.

Both the above task to be done by python program so that the end result is bpython shell.

Output of `which bpython`

[image]

Comment: What does `which bpython` return inside the Cygwin shell?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: It returns `/usr/bin/bpython`. See edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file named `bpython.bat` (contents below) and put it in a directory in your Windows `PATH`:

```
@C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c /usr/bin/bpython
```

Comment: I added `bpython.bat` with the above mentioned code to windows `path` but if i write `bpython` in my `command prompt` it doesn't work but if  i write `C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c bpython` in my command prompt it workd perfectly.

Comment: @Noob: I meant create a file named `bpython.bat` with the code in my answer and put it in a directory that's in your Windows `PATH`; not add that code directly to `PATH`.

Comment: I did that too but same result.